# sql query for getting same data from database

Tags: mysql

My MYSQL database contains some fields which contains duplicate entries. I want to view all those rows which contains same data. Is there a query for this.

Comment: What same data? which type of data? No, clarification in your question.

Comment: Your question is really unclear, can you elaborate? Do you want to return rows that have duplicate data in a particular field (ie 2 rows contain 'Car' in the field 'Vehicle' so you want to return 'Car | 2'?)

Comment: i want to get all rows which contains same values. but i don't want to give values to query. That is query should return all those rows which contains duplicate entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `mycolumn` is the column that has duplicate data, you need to use the following:

```
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable GROUP BY mycolumn HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```